# CGAffineTransform Translation and Rotation produces unrounded transformation result

Tags: avfoundation, cgaffinetransform, affinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

For given transformation calculation,

```
CGAffineTransform preferredTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1, 0, 0, -1, 1920, 1080);
CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-preferredTransform.tx, -preferredTransform.ty), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI));
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(transform1));
```

The output would be `[-1, 1.2246467991473532e-16, -1.2246467991473532e-16, -1, 1920.0000000000002, 1079.9999999999998]` yet I would expect it to be `[-1, 0, 0, -1, 1920, 1080]`

Why the rounding errors? 
Should I apply the transformations differently to produce rounded results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a 32-bit iPad rounding is correct, However, on a 64-bit iPad the rounding errors occurs. Since rotation by M_PI is the same as scaling by -1, this can be easily fixed by changing it to:

```
CGAffineTransform preferredTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1, 0, 0, -1, 1920, 1080);
CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-preferredTransform.tx, -preferredTransform.ty), **CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, -1)**);

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(transform1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The specified rounding errors are due to 64-bit architecture. If you launch on 32-bit simulator, you shouldn't see those rounding errors.

Comment: So, should I be taking care not to use that M_PI code ?

Comment: I'm afraid, the problem is not in M_PI. You can cast M_PI to float and see, that transform remains with rounding errors. Solution I came up with is using `roundf()` function. It fits here because values of transform matrix are in fact integers. I'm not sure how we can fix it for other more complicated transforms.